# Matrix with at least one number in every row and column

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm  trying to build a sparse matrix with at least one random number in every row and column.

In this example I form 4x4 random matrix with sparsity 0.5. 
Then I try to go through rows, check if there are only zeros and add random number to that row to a random position if they are. But this doesn't work, so I would appreciate help.

```
A = sprand (4,4,0.5);
A = full (A);
[n m] = size(A);
x=1;
for i = 1:n
if any(A,2) == 0
j= randperm(m,x);
A(i,j) = rand;
end
end
```

Comment: What do you think this line does? `A(1,randperm(1));`?
Please check your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited it now, but it still doesn't work. My idea is to add a random number on a random position in a row that has all zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sz=4;
A=zeros(sz);
%Generating one random number in every row and column
A(sub2ind([sz sz],randperm(sz),1:sz))=randn(sz,1);   

%The following either generates no indices satisfying the *at least* condition or
%generates some indices since there can be more than one RN in every row and column 
ind = randi([1 sz*sz],1, randi([0 sz*sz],1,1));  
A(ind)=randn(1,length(ind));    %More random numbers on the generated indices
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, for a matrix mxm you want n < m*m random numbers scattered in the matrix, with at least one number in every row and column. How about this solution:

```
% Matrix size
m = 4;
% Unique random rows and columns
rows    = [randperm(m) , randi(m,1,randi(m*m))];
columns = [randperm(m) , randi(m,1,numel(rows)-4)];

% Convert subscripts to linear indices 
idx = unique(sub2ind([m , m] , rows , columns));

% Generate m random numbers
numbers = randn(numel(idx),1);

% Fill in the sparse matrix
A = zeros(m);
A(idx) = numbers
```

I get:

```
A =

0.5139         0    0.1652         0
     0         0   -0.7116    0.4037
     0         0    1.6185   -0.3431
     0   -0.6699    0.6193         0
```

Comment: This always produces one random number in each row and column while the OP wants *at least* one random number in each row and column

Comment: @Sardar Usama thanks for pointing that detail out, I corrected the code to be compliant with the "at least" bit.

Comment: @Sardar Usama yes, because the `unique` bit might remove those indices generated by `randi`. I tested it with brute force by generating 1000 series of indices, and some of them had length m (i.e., one element per row/column)

Comment: @Sardar Usama (with notifications because one more commentator appeared): rows = [3     2     4     1     4     1     2], columns = [4     2     3     1     3     1     2]. The couples (4,3) , (1,1) and (2,2) generated by randi appear twice, so `numel(unique(sub2ind([m , m] , rows , columns)))` = 4